# Set two columns for a flow inside a custom component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, column

For a regular Lightning Flow Component this option is available to change the Layout for the flow:
[image]

However, I have my flow inside a custom component:

Component:

```
<div class="slds-theme_default">
    <br/>
    <lightning:flow aura:id="RTAflow" onstatuschange="{!c.flowStatusChange}"/>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var flow = component.find("RTAflow");
        var inputVariables = [
        {
        name : "recordId",
        type : "SObject",
        value: component.get("v.recordId")
    }
];
flow.startFlow("PPI_RTA", inputVariables);
```

My question is:
Is it possible to change the Layout for the flow in the Component or Controller?